# Just upgrade my site to 1.9.3.0 and got error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity_group_price.is_percent'

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Before I was using Magento 1.9.2.4 and today I got message that need to upgrade my magento with latest update some critical updates too.

After upgrading my website from downloader section everything went well no error etc, two things happen that I notices after update my index.php permission was change to 666 website is opening correctly I mean front page display, but when I click on any product It show error page with following information.

There has been an error processing your request

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity_group_price.is_percent' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value_id` AS `price_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`all_groups`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`customer_group_id` AS `cust_group`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value` AS `price`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`is_percent` FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price` WHERE (entity_id='84') AND (website_id = 0)

Trace:
    #0 /home/MyWebsite/public_html/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[42S22]...')

   #1 /home/MyWebsite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(661): Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[42S22]...')
   #2 /home/MyWebsite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1641): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterLo...', Arr
```

Not know how to roll back because I did not get backup as they says it is stable, or not able to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Delete the contents of `var/cache/`

For the future, remember to turn off Compiler, all Indexes, and all Caches prior to performing an update.

What happened, is that the configuration cache is still active, and prevents Magento from detecting that database changes are necessary.

Comment: I have the same problem. Deleting the cache does not solve it.

Comment: @user3478148 It should solve it, if your Magento installation is configured to use the file system for caching. Otherwise you need to flush whatever else you have set up for caching.

Once the cache is cleared, Magento will collect the new configuration files installed with the update, detect the database version mismatch and trigger the migration.

Answer (score 17):

The issue is caused by a missing column named: `is_percent` in the table `catalog_product_entity_group_price`

Magento 1.9.3 includes an upgrade file that creates that column in the database. The file is located here: `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.19.1.4-1.6.0.0.19.1.5.php`

When the cache is enabled the installer can’t run the upgrade script, causing the error reported by the OP. Another possible cause of a failed upgrade script is if you refresh the frontend or backend before all files have been uploaded via FTP.

If flushing the cache doesn’t solve the problem (be sure to refresh any external cache like Redis) you can try the following:

1) Open the `core_resource` table

2) Locate the `catalog_setup` row

3) If the current value for `version` and `data_versions` is: `1.6.0.0.19.1.5` then change both values to `1.6.0.0.19.1.2` and refresh any page of the frontend.

This will force Magento to rerun the upgrade script and create the missing column in the database.

If the value for version and data_version is `1.6.0.0.19.1.2` then you are not properly flushing the cache.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my problems is solved differently I just past all old files and folder I have a found 10 days old files backup, I just past the old one, I olaha error gone, also every where shows that I am have updated version of magneto i,e 1.9.3.0.
Yes It is not proper solution but it work for me.

Comment: I did a manual update after i accidently removed the base magento files with a failed update via the CLI. Above steps did not solve it for me, but after i changed the rights to the www/var folder with "chmod 777 var" in the CLI. Everything worked fine again.

Comment: Saved my night. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thank you... helped me a lot

Comment: superb. Still helping us copy pasters. Daniel FTW!

Answer (score 3):

Delete all files/folders from the folder path "var/cache/"

And make sure you disabled caching before start upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was Redis cache.  If you aren't sure if you have Redis enabled, check your app/etc/local.xml file.

To flush Redis cache:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the table exists.

Check this table (sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly) wheater 'product_type_id' columns is in it. If 'product_type_id' column is in table then re-index and refresh cache. If 'product_type_id' column is not in that table then you need to create the structure like the image attached.

[image: Database view sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly]

Answer (score 0):

Today I have also faced the same issue and I have resolved by following steps:

1. Run the below query in database

   ALTER TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly` ADD `product_type_id` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL AFTER `product_id` ;

   ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_group_price` ADD `is_percent` SMALLINT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is Percent';
2. Delete the contents of var/cache/