# Magento cron error

Tags: php, magento

I have a website in Magento.

Recently i have upgraded from version 1.9.1.1 to 1.9.3.1. Everday day iam getting email with a cron error.

The error reads:

```
"Product alerts cron warnings: SQLSTATE[42S22]: 

Column not found: 1054
Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity_group_price.is_percent' in 'field list', query was: 

SELECT `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value_id` AS `price_id`, 
`catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`website_id`,
`catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`all_groups`,
`catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`customer_group_id` AS cust_group`,
`catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value` AS `price`,
`catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`is_percent`
FROM
  `catalog_product_entity_group_price`
WHERE 
  (entity_id='3754') AND (website_id IN(0, '5'))
```

Comment: Well, the error message is crystal clear, is it not? Table `catalog_product_entity_group_price` does not have a column `is_percent`. So the query fails.

Comment: the table have "is_percent" but empty table.

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt that. The error message is clear: such column does not exist. Maybe some minor typing difference? Case sensivity? Similar table? Other database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012715/just-upgrade-my-site-to-1-9-3-0-and-got-error-sqlstate42s22-column-not-found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Just upgrade my site to 1.9.3.0 and got error SQLSTATE\[42S22\]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog\_product\_entity\_group\_price.is\_percent'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012715/just-upgrade-my-site-to-1-9-3-0-and-got-error-sqlstate42s22-column-not-found)